# To match the filename with version from the beginning

Tags: regex

Here is a regex to match everything from the beginning of the string up to (but not including) the first dot:

```
^[^.]+
```

That is:

```
string     | matched part
----------------------    
foo.txt    | foo
foo.tar.gz | foo
```

I need to tweak it so that it should include the things like "1.15" or "1.5.1". That is:

```
string           | matched part
-------------------------------
foo_1.15.txt     | foo_1.15
foo_1.5.1.tar.gz | foo_1.5.1
```

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[^.]+[.0-9]*(?=\..+$)
```

[See demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/K6MZA3/2)

**EDIT:** To also match `aaa`, `aaa_1`, `aaa_1.15` and `aaa_1.15.20`, You can make `\..+` part optional, which give this regex:

```
^[^.]+[.0-9]*(?=(?:\..+)?$)
```

[See demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/K6MZA3/3/tests)

Comment: Upvoted and aproved. However, could you improve it so that it will match the following cases as well: `aaa`, `aaa_1`, `aaa_1.15`, `aaa_1.15.20`? Each of these string should be matched from start to end. I haven't metioned this requitement in the original question, but it was implicitly assumed.

Comment: @johnc.j. I've updated the answer; hope it helps :)